# Detail View from TableView, Parsing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, detailsview

Can someone please help me, I looked everywhere to figure this out and nothing worked so far. I need to pass some data from `table view to detail view` and stick it into `labels` and `Uiimage`.

Data tableview is pulling comes from Parse database I created and seems to get pulled fine into the Tableview but I would like to use the `same array` that tableview is using for its data to fill out the detail view.

I am using 2 columns from parse to fill out this tableview Title and sub, and another tow columns to fill out the label and image. Here is my code so far. There is a bunch of variables that i was using in this code in DetailView

```
.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BooksTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,NSObject >
{
    NSArray * Booksarray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *bookstableview;
@end



.m

#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
#import "BookDetailViewController.h"

@interface BooksTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BooksTableViewController

@synthesize bookstableview;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(RetrieveDatafromParse)];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void) RetrieveDatafromParse {
    PFQuery * getbooks = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BooksTableView"];

    [getbooks findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            Booksarray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: objects];
        }
        [bookstableview reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return Booksarray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [bookstableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    PFObject * tempObject = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Books"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [tempObject objectForKey:@"Code"];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BookDetailViewController * detailVC=[[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailVC.BookImage.image=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailVC.bookDesc.text=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailVC.bookTitle.text=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass: [BookDetailViewController class]]) {
        BookDetailViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"SetFile:");

        if ([destination respondsToSelector:selector]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.bookstableview indexPathForCell:sender];

            PFObject * object = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"BooksTableView"];
             [destination setValue:file forKey:@"file"];
        }


    }
}


@end



.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface BookDetailViewController : UIViewController <NSObject> {


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *BookImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookDesc;
@property (weak,nonatomic)PFFile *file;
@end




 .m


#import "BookDetailViewController.h"
#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
@interface BookDetailViewController ()




@implementation BookDetailViewController

@synthesize BookImage,bookTitle,bookDesc,file,bookInfo,Picture,object2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {


        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [self performSelector:@selector(RetrieveObjectsFromParse)];
    self.bookTitle.text = [self.file objectForKey:@"Books"];
    self.BookImage.image = [self.file objectForKey:@"BookImage"];
    self.bookDesc.text =[self.file objectForKey:@"BookDetails"];

}


-(void)RetrieveObjectsFromParse {
    PFQuery * GetObjects = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BooksTableView"];

    [GetObjects findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            details =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: objects];
        };
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    }];

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**#1** create a segue from controller to controller:

**#2** Give your segue an Id for example `detailSegue`.

**#3** Perform the segue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

**#4** Implement the segue delegate:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    BookDetailViewController *detailVC = (BookDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.bookDesc.text=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //I uncommented that because it looks like a typo, same value 3 times?
    //detailVC.BookImage.image=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //detailVC.bookTitle.text=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
}
```

---

If this is the log you get:

> 2014-03-21 15:06:20.151 BookStore[25539:90b]
>   BookIndex= { BookDetails = "Test
>   test"; BookImage = ""; Books = Languages; Code =
>   104; }

Then you need to do it like this instead:

```
detailVC.bookTitle.text=[[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Books"];
detailVC.bookDesc.text= [[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"BookDetails"];
detailVC.BookImage.image=[[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"BookImage"];
```

Or to make it shorter:

```
NSArray *bookAtIndex = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailVC.bookTitle.text=[bookAtIndex objectForKey:@"Books"];
detailVC.bookDesc.text= [bookAtIndex objectForKey:@"BookDetails"];
detailVC.BookImage.image=[bookAtIndex objectForKey:@"BookImage"];
```

or even shorter

```
NSArray *bookAtIndex = Booksarray[indexPath.row];
detailVC.bookTitle.text= bookAtIndex[@"Books"];
detailVC.bookDesc.text= bookAtIndex[@"BookDetails"];
detailVC.BookImage.image= bookAtIndex[@"BookImage"];
```

Comment: Segue works great just the data isn't loading into label and UIImage

Comment: that's what I pointed out to you, you assign `[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` 3 times even `detailVC.BookImage.image=[Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` thats your issue.I advice you to add some loggin

Comment: Well i did that to load book image , book title and bookdesc , into labels and UIImage…i am super confused. this has been killing me all day

Comment: @user3443461 just log it `NSLog(@"Bookarray=%@", Booksarray);` and 
`NSLog(@"BookIndex=%@", [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];);`

Comment: 2014-03-21 15:06:20.151 BookStore[25539:90b] BookIndex=<BooksTableView:h6rgmKG0be:(null)> {
    BookDetails = "Test test";
    BookImage = "<PFFile: 0x9a6be00>";
    Books = Languages;
    Code = 104;
}
2014-03-21 15:06:20.152 BookStore[25539:90b] Warning: Attempt to present <BookDetailViewController: 0xb2a51a0> on <UINavigationController: 0x9d71000> while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: Yeah, when i saw the log i thought of that but didn't know the code. Still doesn't show data in detail view

Comment: I think something is wrong with the segue, does it matter if you connect the entire BooksTableView to DetailView using segue in comparison if you connect just the prototype cell to detail view?

Comment: There are different ways to create segues you know, depends on what you have, check this project https://mega.co.nz/#!yRA1wIqS!8587vXHNehvihPEkBkjW_bgDFYH3MLaPJsAQ14uJCm8 see if it helps you

Comment: Yeah I've tried all the ways I believe…Just don't understand why it won't input the objects into these fields. It shouldn't be this difficult

Comment: this should have worked, run/test the project I gave you. make sure you log stuff. you dont get errors? something is not connected properly unfortunately I cant guess

Comment: 2014-03-21 15:54:29.839 BookStore[26131:90b] Warning: Attempt to present <BookDetailViewController: 0x9a7a3f0> on <UINavigationController: 0x9d86640> while a presentation is in progress!   Maybe that has to do with it not showing data?

Comment: I only got that navigation warning, the one you sent me works perfectly, i think I'm going to try to assign strings and then place them in labels

Comment: OMG that WORKED!!!! SO gooddd!! yes yes hess hahahaha…Alright now how can i using the same or similar method change the picture? I can't save it to string but maybe as an object whats the command for that?

Comment: I just have 1 more question so in order to import that data from array i tweaked ur answer up there a little and i placed the string i created in detail view in place of bookTitle.text on the segue. Seems though i can't use same method for image.I tried to create a PFFile and PFObject but it comes up with incompatible pointer. What other pointer can i use to assign to UIImage?

Comment: What is `PFFile` an Image?

Comment: Ahh its part of Parse framework. It doesn't work for my picture thought. I tried creating UIImage to capture the image from array and assign it to my UIImage view. No Errors, but image doesn't show up. My labels are working though.

Comment: Thats not a good idea, pass the image to an image property , then in your detailed view, assign the image in viewdidload to the imageView. but dont set it directly

Comment: Yeah i mean thats what i did, i assigned @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage * picture;    but i get this download error now 2014-03-21 16:44:37.310 BookStore[26763:90b] -[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ab4fa0
2014-03-21 16:44:37.342 BookStore[26763:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ab4fa0'

Comment: Not sure how  `PFFile` is defined I will make some research, you should post a new question with just that issue, only show the relevant code.  You can give me the link in the comments. Im going home talk to you in a few